# SQL get first occurence and last

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

let suppose we got this kind of table :

```
UserID  ID    FLAG
 1      1      red
 2      2      white
 3      1      white
 4      2      green
 5      2     Brown
 6      5     White
 7      1     Blue
 8      3     Green
 9      4     Green
 10     2     Red
 11     4     Green
 12     3     Black
```

I want to get the first flag and the last for both ID. I tried to use min/max function but it only gave me the first and last row of the table . I tried to use "first" too but apparently it doesnt work with sql Server.

Desired Output for first occurence:

```
ID    Flag
1      red
2      white
3      Green
4      Green
5      White
```

Desired Output For Last Occurence :

```
ID    Flag
1         Blue
2         Red
3         Black
4         Green
5         White
```

Comment: is there any other id in table?

Comment: Yes , it is just a sample but you can suppose there is like 10k+ differents id's

Comment: can you please add some more data and also required output, so we can help you easily

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and specify the expected result as table (formatted, as above.)

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense because there is no internal order in the database.  You need to tell us _how_ you got the order above if you want to write a query which can use it to determine the "first" and "last" flags.

Comment: @Random_Display_Name Why is "BLUE" the last one? By what order? There is no order in your output, and the optimizer may give you the records differently each time you select them.

Comment: The "order"  here is determined by the row number and only the row number.

Comment: what row number ? The rownumber of sql server can be different everytime you do a  select on this table. If you dont have any column like a datetime or an ID then this is impossible

Comment: Row number by itself does not create order, it only numbers the records according to an order imposed by another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor a column which defines the sorting criteria
The order we see on your sample data does not ensure that the sorting is as is in the table
I added the "ident" identity column numbering rows from 1 to n..

Then you can use following sample script with [SQL First_Value() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/first_value-sql-analytic-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

```
--alter table flags add ident int identity(1,1)
select distinct
    id, 
    FIRST_VALUE(flag) over (partition by id order by ident) first,
    FIRST_VALUE(flag) over (partition by id order by ident desc) last
from flags
```

Output is as wanted
[image]

Comment: Happy to see that it worked :) Take care if you decide to use LAST_VALUE() function, please check tutorial http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-last_value-analytic-function-sample-in-sqlserver2012.aspx since you need to add "rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following" after the ORDER BY in LAST_VALUE() partition by clause

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with defining the "min" as the alphabetically smallest flag name, and max as the alphabetically greatest flag name, then one option here is to just do a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT ID,
       MIN(FLAG) AS minFlag,
       MAX(FLAG) AS maxFlag
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no "first" and "last" row, unless another column specifies the rows.

Assuming you have such a column, say one called `createdat`, then you can use `row_number()`.  For the "first" row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by createdat asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

For the last, you would use `desc` instead of `asc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        Flag,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UserID) AS MinPartNo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UserID Desc) AS MaxPartNo            
    FROM @tblTest
)
SELECT 
    ID,
    Flag AS FirstRows
FROM T
WHERE MaxPartNo=0

For Last Row:

SELECT 
    ID,
    Flag AS LastRows
FROM T
WHERE MinPartNo=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not popular method, but if you don't have any identity column you can use `ROW_NUMBER() ... ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RN
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
                        c.ID,
                        c.FLAG,
                        c1.FLAG
FROM cte c
CROSS JOIN cte c1
WHERE c.ID = c1.ID
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY c.RN, c1.RN DESC)
```

Output:

```
ID  FLAG    FLAG
2   white   Red
1   red     Blue
3   Green   Black
4   Green   Green
5   White   White
```